# Using javascript how do I make a CSS id appear and disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fadein, absolute

I want to make a video appear when flipping to a certain page of this application: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip.html  Here is some of my amateur code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (page === 2)
  { 
$("iframe").show();
  }
  else
  { 
$("iframe").hide();
  }

});
```

It connects to an iframe tag that is absolutely positioned. Is that the right approach?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Where did you add the conditional statement? It would be better if you posted your code instead of theirs.

Comment: Please paste *your* code - not a copy of a function from a tutorial. We can't debug this...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only check the page **once** - when it's initially loaded.

You will want to put that `if` statement inside a click handler...

```
$('#elementYouClicked').live('click', function() {
   if (page === 2) {
      //show
   } else {
      //hide
   }
});
```

If this is not what you are asking, can you elaborate on your question please?